# How segment an audio file of keyboard keystrokes in order to isolate each keystroke sound

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, keystroke

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to recognize keystrokes on a keyboard from audio recordings.
My current approach involves segmenting the audio into segments corresponding to each keystroke sound. I've tried using a trigger to detect the sound of each keystroke, but this method isn't reliable every time.
I'm therefore seeking suggestions on the best way to isolate each keystroke sound in an audio file so that I can label my data and use it in my AI model for keystroke recognition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to segment with a split.py script found on the github of Charles Grassin : https://github.com/CGrassin/keyboard_audio_hack.git where he uses :

```
def split_file(file, time_before=0.025, time_after=0.2, trigger=1000, normalize_result=False):
    outputs = []

    # Open file
    sample_rate, a = read(file)
    a = np.array(a,dtype=float)
    
    # Compute params
    length_after = (int)(time_after*sample_rate)
    length_before = (int)(time_before*sample_rate)
    
    # Display sound (debug)
    #plt.plot(a)
    #plt.show()
    
    i = 0
    while i < a.size :
        # End of usable recording
        if(i+length_after > a.size):
            break;
        if (a[i] > trigger and i >= length_before):
            sub = a[i-length_before:i+length_after]
            if(normalize_result): sub = normalize(sub)
            outputs.append(sub)
            i += length_after
        i += 1
    
    return outputs, sample_rate;
```

Comment: There is no perfect answer to what you are asking. A lot of research has been done around the same field and more is yet to be done. Find some here: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/sp/2022/7994191/.
A quick POC would be to simply pass the audio through a pre processor before doing what you are doing right now. One easy thing that can be done is to perform a FFT on the audio signal and isolate the frequencies that correspond to keystrokes. Remove the frequencies that don't correspond to keystrokes and inverse FFT to reconstruct your signal/audio file, which then goes to your existing function